# Can I create custom Array with custom constructor?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class that would inherit everything from Array class but has its own constructor.

The idea is something like this:

```
function Array2(value) 
{
    this.push(value*value);
};
Array2.prototype = new Array();
Array2(4);
```

Obviously this doesn't work because "this.push" doesn't work, because Array2 is not yet based on Array.

Comment: Why do you think `this.push` doesn't work?

Comment: Please use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) or else Cthulhu will be coming for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code doesn't work because you didn't call it with `new` keyword which means that `this` is equal to `window`.

```
var a = new Array2(4);
```

Comment: @Tom, please if this's the answer.Accept it.

Comment: It is, but I need to wait 3 more minutes :)